# Can't assign JSON response data to $scope variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I'm trying to assign JSON response data from `BookService.GetBookDetail(item)` to my `$scope.detailData` so i can put it in my `detail.html` template. My problem is with `{{detailData}}` in `detail.html` which for some reason does not show the detailData i want. Can somebody tell me why my `{{detailData}}` isn't show anything? Here's my code in app.js :

```
App.factory("BookService", function($http, $log){
    //var getData = []; 
    return{
            GetBookDetail: function(item){
                return $http.get("http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/"+item);
            }
        }
})

function AppController($scope, $http, $log, BookService){
  $scope.query = '';
  $scope.brand = true;
  $scope.dataDump = "Hello World";

  $scope.loadBooks = function(){
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.brand = false;
        $http.get("http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/"+$scope.query)
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.dataBook = response.data.Books;
                $scope.dataSearch = response.data;
                $scope.loading = false;
                $log.info(response.data);
                $scope.query = "";
            });
  }

  $scope.detailBook = function(item){
      console.log(item);
      BookService.GetBookDetail(item).then(function(result){
         $scope.detailData = result.data;
      });
  }

}

App.controller("AppController", ["$scope", "$http", "$log", "BookService", AppController]);
```

I'm using ionic framework. Here's my `detail.html` template. The whole `{{detailData.props}}` are showing nothing with the exception for `{{dataDump}}` which is showing the dataDump value "Hello World".

```
<ion-content ng-controller="AppController" class="padding background has-header">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
            <img ng-src="{{ detailData.Image }}" alt="">
            <h2>{{ detailData.Title }}</h2>
            <h2>{{ detailData.Author }}</h2>
            <h3>{{ detailData.SubTitle }} </h3>
            <h4>{{ detailData.Description }}</h4>
            <h4>{{ dataDump }}</h4>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Here's how i manage my 2 templates :

```
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
       $stateProvider
            .state('home',{
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
            })
        .state('detail', {
                url: '/detail',
                templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html'
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    });
```

I'm desperate to know why my binding expression in `detail.html` is not working. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: please provide your `service` or `factory` code. or rather provide a codepen.

Answer (score 3):

Inject the `$rootScope` in the controller:

Change `$scope.detailData`  to `$rootScope.detailData`.

`$rootScope.detailData = result.data`

OR

Remove the `ng-controller` from the ion-content. (you should **not** define controllers in HTML)

Have a habit of defining the `controller` in the `ui-router` itself.

As you stated that you have defined the controller in the home.html as well as the `detail.html`, So both the controller is making `different scopes` as result of which you are not getting the values.

I hope this will work for you!!

Comment: I already call the method from ng-click in my home.html template. Here's my home.html template :  `<ion-item ng-repeat="item in dataBook" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" href="#/detail" ng-click="detailBook(item.ID)">
      <img ng-src="{{ item.Image }}" alt="">
      <h2>{{ item.Title }}</h2>
      <h3>{{ item.SubTitle }} </h3>
      <p>{{ item.Description }}</p>
     </ion-item>`

Comment: So in the home.html page is it Holding the same    ng-controller="AppController"  , check which controller you have placed

Comment: the console.log(result.data) returns a json that look like this : `{ "Error": "0", "Time": 0.00146, "ID": 1306953553, "Title": "Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML", "SubTitle": "A Learner's Companion to HTML, CSS, and XHTML", "Description": "Tired of reading HTML books that only make sense after you're an expert? ...etc", "Author": "Elisabeth Robson, Eric Freeman", "ISBN": "9780596101978", "Year": "2005", "Page": "704", "Publisher": "O'Reilly Media", "Image": "s.it-ebooks-api.info/3/head_first_html_with_css__xhtml.jpg";, "Download": "filepi.com/i/bsMyy1H"; }`

Comment: in home.html i'm using the same controller. I put in `<ion-pane ng-controller="AppController"></ion-pane>` which wrapped the whole content of my home.html

Comment: I have updated my answer please check , Please inject the $rootScope in the contoller

Comment: `<ion-content ng-controller="AppController" class="padding background has-header"> ` you have placed it two times it   is making a new scope, remove the controller from the ion content

Comment: Finally it worked.!! Thanks @Vishal. The solution was to use `$rootScope` rather than `$scope` for my `detailData`. Although i'm still confused why isn't $scope working?

Comment: Although i've modified and define my AppController in ui-router but it still doesn't work without `$rootScope` idk why.

Comment: It is not working because you have defined the controllers two times, So what is happening is that two controllers are being initialized with different scopes. You are setting the scope in one different controller object and trying to recieve it another controller object so it obvios it wont work

Comment: Basically i just remove the ng-controller from all the templates and add controller: AppController to the router that look like this : `App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
   .state('home',{
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: AppController
   })
   .state('detail', {
    url: '/detail',
    templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html',
    controller: AppController
   })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

 });`

Comment: Please remove the controller mentioned in the detail one, i.e.
`App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){ $stateProvider .state('home',{ url: '/home', templateUrl: 'templates/home.html', controller: AppController }) .state('detail', { url: '/detail', templateUrl: 'templates/detail.html' }) $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); });' This will work for you

Comment: I've remove the controller mentioned in the 'detail' state but looks like i still have to use `$rootScope` because `$scope` alone isn't working idk why. Does it mean that in my case, my best solution is to use `$rootScope`?

Answer (score 1):

The `$http.get` method returns a promise. In your `GetBookDetail` method, you need to return this promise, and access the data once it's resolved (as you have when using the `$http.get` method in your `AppController`).

To do this, try the following:

```
    GetBookDetail: function(item){
        return $http.get("http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/"+item);
    }


BookService.GetBookDetail(item)
.then(function(result){
    $scope.detailData = result.data;
});
```

Comment: I've modified my code as your suggestion but still the `{{detailData.props}}` isn't showing in my `detail.html`. So i'm still facing the same problem here. What really puzzles me is that when i'm `$log.info($scope.detailData)`, it gives me back the correct object response. But somehow, it just won't show using the `{{detailData.props}}` binding expression in `detail.html`.

Comment: I updated my example - make sure you are setting `$scope.detailData` inside the resolve of the promise. Also, what does `$scope.detailData` log look like?

Comment: the log returns an object that look like this :

Comment: {
  "Error": "0",
  "Time": 0.00146,
  "ID": 1306953553,
  "Title": "Head First HTML with CSS & XHTML",
  "SubTitle": "A Learner's Companion to HTML, CSS, and XHTML",
  "Description": "Tired of reading HTML books that only make sense after you're an expert? ...etc",
  "Author": "Elisabeth Robson, Eric Freeman",
  "ISBN": "9780596101978",
  "Year": "2005",
  "Page": "704",
  "Publisher": "O'Reilly Media",
  "Image": "http://s.it-ebooks-api.info/3/head_first_html_with_css__xhtml.jpg",
  "Download": "http://filepi.com/i/bsMyy1H"
}

Answer (score 0):

`BookService.GetBookDetail(item);` returns a promise. Do something like:

```
BookService.GetBookDetail(item).then(function(result){
    $scope.detailData = result.data;
});
```

And then have your service simply return:

```
GetBookDetail: function(item){
     return $http.get("http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/"+item);
}
```

Comment: I've modified my code as your suggestion but still the `{{detailData.props}}` isn't showing in my `detail.html`. So i'm still facing the same problem here. What really puzzles me is that when i'm `$log.info($scope.detailData)`, it gives me back the correct object response. But somehow, it just won't  show using the `{{detailData.props}}` binding expression in `detail.html`.

Comment: Please do console.log(result.data) and tell exactly what you are getting